# setInterval response only once instead of 1000

Tags: javascript, setinterval, opacity

I want to change the opacity of table with setInterval:

```
    window.setInterval(function () {
        if (document.getElementById("goalkeepers").style.opacity != 1)
            document.getElementById("goalkeepers").style.opacity = document.getElementById("goalkeepers").style.opacity + 0.001;
    }, 1);
```

When I run this code it do it only once, the opacity of the table is only 0.001.
What is the problem?

Comment: Have you tried changing `!= 1` to `< 1`?

Comment: Have you tried a larger delay?

Comment: Yes for both, I tried and steal only once.

Comment: without a ClearInterval your code should be repeated forever, put a debugger before your if to check

Comment: I would try `parseFloat`, just in case the value you are getting isn't a number.

Comment: Yes the parseFloat fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: because opacity is a string `"0.001" + 0.001` results in string `"0.0010.001"` and ignored as invalid value

Answer (score 1):

There are several things wrong with the code itself:

- DRY, you are calling `getElementById` to get the same element a LOT.
- You are assuming that `0.001 + 0.001 + 0.001 + ...` a thousand times will add up to exactly 1. This is not true in computers, because of how floating point numbers work. You should use `< 1` instead of `!= 1`
- *Retrieving a style is always a string. Therefore the result is trying to be `0.0010.001`, ie. concatenation.*
- You are using an interval of `1ms`. Intervals should generally not be less than about `20`.

Try:

```
var tbl = document.getElementById('goalkeepers');
tbl.style.opacity = 0;
tbl.style.transition = "opacity 1s linear";
setTimeout(function() {
    // delay the actual opacity setting so it will be transitioned
    tbl.style.opacity = 1;
},10);
```

Comment: Won't you need to use something like jQuery animate for a transition?

Comment: @bukko Erm, noooooooo... Basic CSS!

Comment: So, you don't need the basic CSS: `transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;`?

Comment: Oh yeah you do - I didn't notice that! My apologies :D

Comment: :p It's not Monday any more XD

Comment: I did not know that the browser would make the transition smooth just by setting the opacity, very neat +1. Does this work on all browsers?

Answer (score 0):

These guys beat me to it while I was making a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7dxXM/), But I will post anyway.

```
var gk = document.getElementById("goalkeepers"),
    animation = window.setInterval(function () {
        if (gk.style.opacity < 1) {
            gk.style.opacity = Number(gk.style.opacity) + 0.001;
        }
        else {
            clearInterval(animation);
        }
    }, 1);
```

They both are correct about using `<` istead of `!=` for the float type comparison, the string value of `style.xxx` and only calling `document.getElementById` once.

You should consider excepting one of their answers.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
var t= window.setInterval(function () {

if (parseInt(document.getElementById("goalkeepers").style.opacity) != 1)
{
    document.getElementById("goalkeepers").style.opacity = Number(document.getElementById("goalkeepers").style.opacity) + 0.001;
}
else
{
    clearInterval(t);   
}
}, 1);
```

You opacity is not incrementing, so used Number() also you have clear the interval once opacity reached 1 else it will keep calling might slow down your browser after some time.

Comment: `0.001 + 0.001 + ...` a thousand times is `1.0000000000000007` (in floating point numbers), which is NOT `1`.

Comment: Yes... `eval(new Array(1001).join("+0.001"))` gives the above result, and if you don't trust that `eval`, try `for( i=0; i!=1; i+=0.001);` and watch your browser burn.

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol. What i'm asking is have you tried the same code what i have placed in my answer?

Comment: I don't need to. I know it will never end. While the effect might not be visible, try adding `alert("Done!")` to the `else` block. Then wait for it to appear.

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol  Please don't make any assumptions. I tried that code. It works.

Comment: It does not work. Period. You cannot add floats together and expect them to add up to an exact integer (unless said floats are powers of 2)